# Grid gap inconsistent between rows and columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make the space between the rows equal to the columns gap
but I really don't know what property is creating this gap between the rows. I tried fiddling around with grid gap to no success.

Also when the screen size reduces the right margin disappears.

Struggling to make this gallery work responsively.

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  max-width: 90rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.grid>[class*="column-"] {
  display: block;
}

.first {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: -1;
  order: -1;
}

.last {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 13;
  -ms-flex-order: 12;
  order: 12;
}

.align-top {
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: start;
}

.align-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.align-bottom {
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  align-items: end;
}

.column-xs-1 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.3333333333%;
  flex-basis: 8.3333333333%;
  max-width: 8.3333333333%;
}

.column-xs-2 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.6666666667%;
  flex-basis: 16.6666666667%;
  max-width: 16.6666666667%;
}

.column-xs-3 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.column-xs-4 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.3333333333%;
  flex-basis: 33.3333333333%;
  max-width: 33.3333333333%;
}

.column-xs-5 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.6666666667%;
  flex-basis: 41.6666666667%;
  max-width: 41.6666666667%;
}

.column-xs-6 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.column-xs-7 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.3333333333%;
  flex-basis: 58.3333333333%;
  max-width: 58.3333333333%;
}

.column-xs-8 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.6666666667%;
  flex-basis: 66.6666666667%;
  max-width: 66.6666666667%;
}

.column-xs-9 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
}

.column-xs-10 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.3333333333%;
  flex-basis: 83.3333333333%;
  max-width: 83.3333333333%;
}

.column-xs-11 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.6666666667%;
  flex-basis: 91.6666666667%;
  max-width: 91.6666666667%;
}

.column-xs-12 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  .column-sm-1 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 8.3333333333%;
    max-width: 8.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-sm-2 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 16.6666666667%;
    max-width: 16.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-sm-3 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .column-sm-4 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 33.3333333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-sm-5 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 41.6666666667%;
    max-width: 41.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-sm-6 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .column-sm-7 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 58.3333333333%;
    max-width: 58.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-sm-8 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 66.6666666667%;
    max-width: 66.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-sm-9 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
    flex-basis: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .column-sm-10 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 83.3333333333%;
    max-width: 83.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-sm-11 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 91.6666666667%;
    max-width: 91.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-sm-12 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62rem) {
  .column-md-1 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 8.3333333333%;
    max-width: 8.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-md-2 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 16.6666666667%;
    max-width: 16.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-md-3 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .column-md-4 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 33.3333333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-md-5 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 41.6666666667%;
    max-width: 41.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-md-6 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .column-md-7 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 58.3333333333%;
    max-width: 58.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-md-8 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 66.6666666667%;
    max-width: 66.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-md-9 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
    flex-basis: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .column-md-10 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 83.3333333333%;
    max-width: 83.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-md-11 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 91.6666666667%;
    max-width: 91.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-md-12 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 75rem) {
  .column-lg-1 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 8.3333333333%;
    max-width: 8.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-lg-2 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 16.6666666667%;
    max-width: 16.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-lg-3 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .column-lg-4 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 33.3333333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-lg-5 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 41.6666666667%;
    max-width: 41.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-lg-6 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .column-lg-7 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 58.3333333333%;
    max-width: 58.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-lg-8 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 66.6666666667%;
    max-width: 66.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-lg-9 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
    flex-basis: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .column-lg-10 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 83.3333333333%;
    max-width: 83.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-lg-11 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 91.6666666667%;
    max-width: 91.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-lg-12 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
  }
  .grid>[class*="column-"] {
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .column-xs-1 {
    grid-column-start: span 1;
    grid-column-end: span 1;
  }
  .column-xs-2 {
    grid-column-start: span 2;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
  }
  .column-xs-3 {
    grid-column-start: span 3;
    grid-column-end: span 3;
  }
  .column-xs-4 {
    grid-column-start: span 4;
    grid-column-end: span 4;
  }
  .column-xs-5 {
    grid-column-start: span 5;
    grid-column-end: span 5;
  }
  .column-xs-6 {
    grid-column-start: span 6;
    grid-column-end: span 6;
  }
  .column-xs-7 {
    grid-column-start: span 7;
    grid-column-end: span 7;
  }
  .column-xs-8 {
    grid-column-start: span 8;
    grid-column-end: span 8;
  }
  .column-xs-9 {
    grid-column-start: span 9;
    grid-column-end: span 9;
  }
  .column-xs-10 {
    grid-column-start: span 10;
    grid-column-end: span 10;
  }
  .column-xs-11 {
    grid-column-start: span 11;
    grid-column-end: span 11;
  }
  .column-xs-12 {
    grid-column-start: span 12;
    grid-column-end: span 12;
  }
  @media (min-width: 48rem) {
    .column-sm-1 {
      grid-column-start: span 1;
      grid-column-end: span 1;
    }
    .column-sm-2 {
      grid-column-start: span 2;
      grid-column-end: span 2;
    }
    .column-sm-3 {
      grid-column-start: span 3;
      grid-column-end: span 3;
    }
    .column-sm-4 {
      grid-column-start: span 4;
      grid-column-end: span 4;
    }
    .column-sm-5 {
      grid-column-start: span 5;
      grid-column-end: span 5;
    }
    .column-sm-6 {
      grid-column-start: span 6;
      grid-column-end: span 6;
    }
    .column-sm-7 {
      grid-column-start: span 7;
      grid-column-end: span 7;
    }
    .column-sm-8 {
      grid-column-start: span 8;
      grid-column-end: span 8;
    }
    .column-sm-9 {
      grid-column-start: span 9;
      grid-column-end: span 9;
    }
    .column-sm-10 {
      grid-column-start: span 10;
      grid-column-end: span 10;
    }
    .column-sm-11 {
      grid-column-start: span 11;
      grid-column-end: span 11;
    }
    .column-sm-12 {
      grid-column-start: span 12;
      grid-column-end: span 12;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 62rem) {
    .column-md-1 {
      grid-column-start: span 1;
      grid-column-end: span 1;
    }
    .column-md-2 {
      grid-column-start: span 2;
      grid-column-end: span 2;
    }
    .column-md-3 {
      grid-column-start: span 3;
      grid-column-end: span 3;
    }
    .column-md-4 {
      grid-column-start: span 4;
      grid-column-end: span 4;
    }
    .column-md-5 {
      grid-column-start: span 5;
      grid-column-end: span 5;
    }
    .column-md-6 {
      grid-column-start: span 6;
      grid-column-end: span 6;
    }
    .column-md-7 {
      grid-column-start: span 7;
      grid-column-end: span 7;
    }
    .column-md-8 {
      grid-column-start: span 8;
      grid-column-end: span 8;
    }
    .column-md-9 {
      grid-column-start: span 9;
      grid-column-end: span 9;
    }
    .column-md-10 {
      grid-column-start: span 10;
      grid-column-end: span 10;
    }
    .column-md-11 {
      grid-column-start: span 11;
      grid-column-end: span 11;
    }
    .column-md-12 {
      grid-column-start: span 12;
      grid-column-end: span 12;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 75rem) {
    .column-lg-1 {
      grid-column-start: span 1;
      grid-column-end: span 1;
    }
    .column-lg-2 {
      grid-column-start: span 2;
      grid-column-end: span 2;
    }
    .column-lg-3 {
      grid-column-start: span 3;
      grid-column-end: span 3;
    }
    .column-lg-4 {
      grid-column-start: span 4;
      grid-column-end: span 4;
    }
    .column-lg-5 {
      grid-column-start: span 5;
      grid-column-end: span 5;
    }
    .column-lg-6 {
      grid-column-start: span 6;
      grid-column-end: span 6;
    }
    .column-lg-7 {
      grid-column-start: span 7;
      grid-column-end: span 7;
    }
    .column-lg-8 {
      grid-column-start: span 8;
      grid-column-end: span 8;
    }
    .column-lg-9 {
      grid-column-start: span 9;
      grid-column-end: span 9;
    }
    .column-lg-10 {
      grid-column-start: span 10;
      grid-column-end: span 10;
    }
    .column-lg-11 {
      grid-column-start: span 11;
      grid-column-end: span 11;
    }
    .column-lg-12 {
      grid-column-start: span 12;
      grid-column-end: span 12;
    }
  }
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #787878;
  background: #fff;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 1.5rem 0 0;
}

a {
  color: #787878;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

a.active {
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

nav {
  padding: 2.5rem 0 2.5rem 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: left;
  -ms-flex-pack: left;
  justify-content: left;
}

nav li {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0;
}

#highlight {
  color: #ea8478;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.gallery {
  padding: 0 0 4rem 0;
}

.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container:hover .img-content-hover {
  display: block;
}

.moto {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.moto:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.img-content-hover {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 1.25rem;
  margin-left: -2rem;
}

.title {
  color: #2e2e2e;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.category {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #787878;
}

.img-content {
  display: none;
}

.social,
.copyright {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.social li {
  display: inline-block;
}

footer {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background: #23272A;
  text-align: center;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  .gallery .grid {
    grid-gap: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62rem) {
  nav ul {
    -webkit-box-pack: right;
    -ms-flex-pack: right;
    justify-content: right;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  .img-container {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .img-container:hover .img-content-hover {
    display: none;
  }
  .img-content {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/8b1cWDyvT7Y" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Smart Watch</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Smart Watch</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/5VXH4RG88gc" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Camera Film</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Camera Film</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/XtUd5SiX464">
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Coffee</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Coffee</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-6">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/JYGnB9gTCls" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Phone</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Phone</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-6">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/-RBuQ2PK_L8" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Keyboard</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Keyboard</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/8b1cWDyvT7Y" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Smart Watch</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Smart Watch</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/5VXH4RG88gc" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Camera Film</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Camera Film</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/XtUd5SiX464">
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Coffee</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Coffee</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-6">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/JYGnB9gTCls" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Phone</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Phone</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-6">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/-RBuQ2PK_L8" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Keyboard</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Keyboard</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to the `grip-gap` property.

In fact, both `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap` render at equal lengths, as you've specified:

```
.gallery .grid {
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

Yes, the gaps appear different.

[image]

But if you highlight the grid, you'll notice the gaps are the same:

[image]

<sup>(Outlined using Chrome dev tools.)</sup>

The problem is caused by the content of grid items not filling the entire height of each item.

And that's caused by default margins on the `figure` element:

[image]

(Read about the [`margin-block-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start) and [`margin-inline-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-start) properties.)

So the solution is to override those margins. Add this to your code:

```
figure.img-container {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qvxas17m/1/)

```css
figure.img-container {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  max-width: 90rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.grid>[class*="column-"] {
  display: block;
}

.first {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: -1;
  order: -1;
}

.last {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 13;
  -ms-flex-order: 12;
  order: 12;
}

.align-top {
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: start;
}

.align-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.align-bottom {
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  align-items: end;
}

.column-xs-1 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.3333333333%;
  flex-basis: 8.3333333333%;
  max-width: 8.3333333333%;
}

.column-xs-2 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.6666666667%;
  flex-basis: 16.6666666667%;
  max-width: 16.6666666667%;
}

.column-xs-3 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.column-xs-4 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.3333333333%;
  flex-basis: 33.3333333333%;
  max-width: 33.3333333333%;
}

.column-xs-5 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.6666666667%;
  flex-basis: 41.6666666667%;
  max-width: 41.6666666667%;
}

.column-xs-6 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.column-xs-7 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.3333333333%;
  flex-basis: 58.3333333333%;
  max-width: 58.3333333333%;
}

.column-xs-8 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.6666666667%;
  flex-basis: 66.6666666667%;
  max-width: 66.6666666667%;
}

.column-xs-9 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
}

.column-xs-10 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.3333333333%;
  flex-basis: 83.3333333333%;
  max-width: 83.3333333333%;
}

.column-xs-11 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.6666666667%;
  flex-basis: 91.6666666667%;
  max-width: 91.6666666667%;
}

.column-xs-12 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  .column-sm-1 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 8.3333333333%;
    max-width: 8.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-sm-2 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 16.6666666667%;
    max-width: 16.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-sm-3 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .column-sm-4 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 33.3333333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-sm-5 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 41.6666666667%;
    max-width: 41.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-sm-6 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .column-sm-7 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 58.3333333333%;
    max-width: 58.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-sm-8 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 66.6666666667%;
    max-width: 66.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-sm-9 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
    flex-basis: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .column-sm-10 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 83.3333333333%;
    max-width: 83.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-sm-11 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 91.6666666667%;
    max-width: 91.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-sm-12 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62rem) {
  .column-md-1 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 8.3333333333%;
    max-width: 8.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-md-2 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 16.6666666667%;
    max-width: 16.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-md-3 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .column-md-4 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 33.3333333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-md-5 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 41.6666666667%;
    max-width: 41.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-md-6 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .column-md-7 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 58.3333333333%;
    max-width: 58.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-md-8 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 66.6666666667%;
    max-width: 66.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-md-9 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
    flex-basis: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .column-md-10 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 83.3333333333%;
    max-width: 83.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-md-11 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 91.6666666667%;
    max-width: 91.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-md-12 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 75rem) {
  .column-lg-1 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 8.3333333333%;
    max-width: 8.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-lg-2 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 16.6666666667%;
    max-width: 16.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-lg-3 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .column-lg-4 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 33.3333333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-lg-5 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 41.6666666667%;
    max-width: 41.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-lg-6 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .column-lg-7 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 58.3333333333%;
    max-width: 58.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-lg-8 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 66.6666666667%;
    max-width: 66.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-lg-9 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
    flex-basis: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .column-lg-10 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.3333333333%;
    flex-basis: 83.3333333333%;
    max-width: 83.3333333333%;
  }
  .column-lg-11 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.6666666667%;
    flex-basis: 91.6666666667%;
    max-width: 91.6666666667%;
  }
  .column-lg-12 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
  }
  .grid>[class*="column-"] {
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .column-xs-1 {
    grid-column-start: span 1;
    grid-column-end: span 1;
  }
  .column-xs-2 {
    grid-column-start: span 2;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
  }
  .column-xs-3 {
    grid-column-start: span 3;
    grid-column-end: span 3;
  }
  .column-xs-4 {
    grid-column-start: span 4;
    grid-column-end: span 4;
  }
  .column-xs-5 {
    grid-column-start: span 5;
    grid-column-end: span 5;
  }
  .column-xs-6 {
    grid-column-start: span 6;
    grid-column-end: span 6;
  }
  .column-xs-7 {
    grid-column-start: span 7;
    grid-column-end: span 7;
  }
  .column-xs-8 {
    grid-column-start: span 8;
    grid-column-end: span 8;
  }
  .column-xs-9 {
    grid-column-start: span 9;
    grid-column-end: span 9;
  }
  .column-xs-10 {
    grid-column-start: span 10;
    grid-column-end: span 10;
  }
  .column-xs-11 {
    grid-column-start: span 11;
    grid-column-end: span 11;
  }
  .column-xs-12 {
    grid-column-start: span 12;
    grid-column-end: span 12;
  }
  @media (min-width: 48rem) {
    .column-sm-1 {
      grid-column-start: span 1;
      grid-column-end: span 1;
    }
    .column-sm-2 {
      grid-column-start: span 2;
      grid-column-end: span 2;
    }
    .column-sm-3 {
      grid-column-start: span 3;
      grid-column-end: span 3;
    }
    .column-sm-4 {
      grid-column-start: span 4;
      grid-column-end: span 4;
    }
    .column-sm-5 {
      grid-column-start: span 5;
      grid-column-end: span 5;
    }
    .column-sm-6 {
      grid-column-start: span 6;
      grid-column-end: span 6;
    }
    .column-sm-7 {
      grid-column-start: span 7;
      grid-column-end: span 7;
    }
    .column-sm-8 {
      grid-column-start: span 8;
      grid-column-end: span 8;
    }
    .column-sm-9 {
      grid-column-start: span 9;
      grid-column-end: span 9;
    }
    .column-sm-10 {
      grid-column-start: span 10;
      grid-column-end: span 10;
    }
    .column-sm-11 {
      grid-column-start: span 11;
      grid-column-end: span 11;
    }
    .column-sm-12 {
      grid-column-start: span 12;
      grid-column-end: span 12;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 62rem) {
    .column-md-1 {
      grid-column-start: span 1;
      grid-column-end: span 1;
    }
    .column-md-2 {
      grid-column-start: span 2;
      grid-column-end: span 2;
    }
    .column-md-3 {
      grid-column-start: span 3;
      grid-column-end: span 3;
    }
    .column-md-4 {
      grid-column-start: span 4;
      grid-column-end: span 4;
    }
    .column-md-5 {
      grid-column-start: span 5;
      grid-column-end: span 5;
    }
    .column-md-6 {
      grid-column-start: span 6;
      grid-column-end: span 6;
    }
    .column-md-7 {
      grid-column-start: span 7;
      grid-column-end: span 7;
    }
    .column-md-8 {
      grid-column-start: span 8;
      grid-column-end: span 8;
    }
    .column-md-9 {
      grid-column-start: span 9;
      grid-column-end: span 9;
    }
    .column-md-10 {
      grid-column-start: span 10;
      grid-column-end: span 10;
    }
    .column-md-11 {
      grid-column-start: span 11;
      grid-column-end: span 11;
    }
    .column-md-12 {
      grid-column-start: span 12;
      grid-column-end: span 12;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 75rem) {
    .column-lg-1 {
      grid-column-start: span 1;
      grid-column-end: span 1;
    }
    .column-lg-2 {
      grid-column-start: span 2;
      grid-column-end: span 2;
    }
    .column-lg-3 {
      grid-column-start: span 3;
      grid-column-end: span 3;
    }
    .column-lg-4 {
      grid-column-start: span 4;
      grid-column-end: span 4;
    }
    .column-lg-5 {
      grid-column-start: span 5;
      grid-column-end: span 5;
    }
    .column-lg-6 {
      grid-column-start: span 6;
      grid-column-end: span 6;
    }
    .column-lg-7 {
      grid-column-start: span 7;
      grid-column-end: span 7;
    }
    .column-lg-8 {
      grid-column-start: span 8;
      grid-column-end: span 8;
    }
    .column-lg-9 {
      grid-column-start: span 9;
      grid-column-end: span 9;
    }
    .column-lg-10 {
      grid-column-start: span 10;
      grid-column-end: span 10;
    }
    .column-lg-11 {
      grid-column-start: span 11;
      grid-column-end: span 11;
    }
    .column-lg-12 {
      grid-column-start: span 12;
      grid-column-end: span 12;
    }
  }
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #787878;
  background: #fff;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 1.5rem 0 0;
}

a {
  color: #787878;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

a.active {
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

nav {
  padding: 2.5rem 0 2.5rem 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: left;
  -ms-flex-pack: left;
  justify-content: left;
}

nav li {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0;
}

#highlight {
  color: #ea8478;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.gallery {
  padding: 0 0 4rem 0;
}

.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container:hover .img-content-hover {
  display: block;
}

.moto {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.moto:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.img-content-hover {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 1.25rem;
  margin-left: -2rem;
}

.title {
  color: #2e2e2e;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.category {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #787878;
}

.img-content {
  display: none;
}

.social,
.copyright {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.social li {
  display: inline-block;
}

footer {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background: #23272A;
  text-align: center;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  .gallery .grid {
    grid-gap: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62rem) {
  nav ul {
    -webkit-box-pack: right;
    -ms-flex-pack: right;
    justify-content: right;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  .img-container {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .img-container:hover .img-content-hover {
    display: none;
  }
  .img-content {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/8b1cWDyvT7Y" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Smart Watch</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Smart Watch</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/5VXH4RG88gc" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Camera Film</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Camera Film</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/XtUd5SiX464">
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Coffee</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Coffee</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-6">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/JYGnB9gTCls" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Phone</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Phone</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-6">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/-RBuQ2PK_L8" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Keyboard</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Keyboard</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/8b1cWDyvT7Y" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Smart Watch</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Smart Watch</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/5VXH4RG88gc" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Camera Film</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Camera Film</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-4">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/XtUd5SiX464">
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Coffee</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Coffee</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-6">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/JYGnB9gTCls" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Phone</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Phone</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="column-xs-12 column-md-6">
        <figure class="img-container">
          <img class="moto" src="https://source.unsplash.com/-RBuQ2PK_L8" />
          <figcaption class="img-content">
            <h2 class="title">Keyboard</h2>
            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
          </figcaption>
          <span class="img-content-hover">
                            <h2 class="title">Keyboard</h2>
                            <h3 class="category">Showcase</h3>
                        </span>
        </figure>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I managed to figure it out but your explanation and links helped improve my understanding of the problem, thank you for taking time out of your day to do so!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some default margin added which threw the whole grid off whack, it has been found and resolved. Many thanks!